# Convert octal to decimal in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

A friend asked how in SQL to convert a varchar which represents an octal value into integer, so I'm placing an answer here and seeing if anyone improves upon it.

I had hoped for a solution that could be run inline as part of query, without having to create any function in the database (e.g if you only have permission to query a database, but not create any new functions or stored procedures in it).

Alternatively, I see that .Net Framework ToInt32 method has easy way of doing this, but seems like jumping through a lot of CLR integration hoops required to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat convoluted - requiring a 2-level scalar subquery

**Setup & Query**

```
declare @t table (oct varchar(10));
insert @t select '7101';
insert @t select '6';
insert @t select '110111';

select *,
       (select sum(val)
        from
           (
            select substring(reverse(t.oct), v.number, 1) * power(8, v.number-1) val
              from master..spt_values v
             where v.type='p' and v.number between 1 and len(t.oct)
           ) x
       ) intVal
  from @t t;
```

**Results**

```
oct        intVal
---------- -----------
7101       3649
6          6
110111     36937
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my quick-n-dirty iterative version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_OctalToInt(@OctalVal varchar(50)) RETURNS BIGINT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos tinyint = 0
    DECLARE @tot bigint = 0
    WHILE @pos < LEN(@OctalVal) BEGIN
        set @tot = @tot + cast(SUBSTRING(@OctalVal, len(@OctalVal) - @pos, 1) as tinyint) * power(8,@pos)
        set @pos = @pos + 1
    END
    RETURN @tot
END
```