# How to convert octa to decimal in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Only found this related answer: [Convert octal to decimal in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409441/convert-octal-to-decimal-in-sql)

Based on https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.html?x=0325,
Octal: **0325** should convert to decimal **213**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer from the SQL Server question can be converted to Postgres. It's actually a bit easier as you can split the string directly into the letters using `string_to_table`

```
create function octal_to_decimal(p_input text)
  returns numeric
as
$$  
  select sum(x.digit::int * 8 ^ (length(p_input) - idx)) as val
  from string_to_table(p_input, null) with ordinality as x(digit, idx) 
$$
language sql
stable;
```

`select octal_to_decimal('0325')` returns `213`

If you are on an older Postgres release, you need to replace `string_to_table(p_input, null)` with `unnest(string_to_array(p_input, null))`

Comment: For older version of postgres change this sum(x.digit::int * 8 ^ (length(p_input) - idx))::numeric ., so you can avoid this ., ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return numeric
DETAIL:  Actual return type is double precision.